# Make a body move using touch down in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I am a newbie in `libgdx`. I working on to make a body move using touch and as soon as the touch is released it must stop moving on !! Its working fine with KeyUp and Key down but I don't know how to implement using touch.

This is my code.I wrote it as a separate class. Here is the class:

```
public Player(World world, float x, float y, float width) {
    this.width = width; //IMP
    height = width * 2;
    BodyDef polygon = new BodyDef();
    polygon.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    polygon.position.set(x, y); //
    polygon.fixedRotation = true;
    //polygon shape

    PolygonShape poly = new PolygonShape();
    poly.setAsBox(width / 2, height / 2); //

    //fixture defn

    FixtureDef polyfixture = new FixtureDef();
    polyfixture.shape = poly;
    polyfixture.friction = 0.8f;  //
    polyfixture.restitution = 0.1f; //
    polyfixture.density = 1; //


    //creating actual body
    polybody = world.createBody(polygon);
    polybody.createFixture(polyfixture);
    // polybody.applyAngularImpulse(52, true);
    //disposing the body

    polysprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/car.jpg"));

    polysprite.setSize(0.5f, 1); //size of mario
    polysprite.setOrigin(polysprite.getWidth() / 2, polysprite.getHeight() / 2);
    polybody.setUserData(polysprite);

    poly.dispose();

}


public void update() {
    polybody.applyForceToCenter(velocity, true);
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.D:
            velocity.x = momentForce;
            //leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
            //leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(-motorspeed);
            //movement.x=speed;
            //System.out.println("key d");

            break;

        case Keys.A:
            velocity.x = -momentForce;
            //leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
            //leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(motorspeed);
            //movement.x=-speed;
            // break;
            //case Keys.S:

            //leftAxis.enableMotor(false);
            break;

        case Keys.W:
            velocity.y = momentForce;
            break;
        case Keys.S:
            velocity.y = -momentForce;

            break;


        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.D:
            velocity.x = 0;
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            velocity.x = 0;
            break;
        case Keys.W:
            velocity.y = 0;
            break;
        case Keys.S:
            velocity.y = 0;
            break;
        default:
            return false;


    }
    return true;
}

@Override

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        //Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        //  touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        // camera.unproject(touchPos);
        velocity.y = momentForce;
    }
    return true;
}


public Body getBody() {
    {
        return polybody;
    }


}
```

This is my code.I tried using touchdown. I tried the body to move by setting certain speed but nothing happens as expected. I am not able to make this body (polygon)move using touch. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide which class does your Player class extends? Also do you have any buttons to control the velocity up or down? because keys are keys so u press Q and do something when you will use touch you need to touch something specific to do something specific. Else the touch will be detected and treated same in any position of the screen. Give some more details and we maybe able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way it works is that you need to tell libgdx that you're using touch controls. In the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) it says you need to use `Input.setInputProcessor(InputProcessor)`.
In the example i found [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx) they use:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

which they've put in the constructor of the class. I think in your case in the Player constructor it should be fine.

Also if you want to make your body stop, you need to tell it to stop just like you did with the key arrows. You need to add something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    velocity.y = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want to make a body move using touch down. When I set velocity.y=some value ,nothing happens @ShadowMitia

Comment: My bad, I thought the body moved. But I think you'll still need this though, I'll update my answer when I have a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot..will wait still @ShadowMitia

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
 //Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
//  touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
 // camera.unproject(touchPos);
velocity.y=momentForce;
}
return true; 
}
```

Since you are overriding it, I suppose you have this method in your class that implements InputProcessor. And since your keyUp() and keyDown() methods work, I suppose you set the class as InputProccessor.
If the above cases are true, then heres a fix for your code.

```
  @Override 
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
 //  touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
 // camera.unproject(touchPos);
velocity.y=momentForce;
return true; 
}
```

All you have to do is to remove the if statement. touchDown() method is only called when the user touches the screen. If you check for Gdx.input.isTouched() inside your touchDown, your code will never pass your if statement because everytime the user touches the screen, he/she will be reffered back to touchDown.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this. In my class I implemented InputProcessor and I added    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); in show method and to make a body move  along x axis on touching the screen I added the following code

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

       Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
          touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
          camera.unproject(touchPos);
          movement.x =speed;
          Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch done ");

    return true;
}
```

So, the body moves along x axis on touching screen.